# How to make minimal example of matter.js work?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, physics-engine, matter.js

I'm trying to use the [matter.js physics library](http://brm.io/matter-js/). I'm using their ["getting started" tutorial](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/wiki/Getting-started), but it can't find the canvas.

Here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Physics test</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/matter-0.8.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Matter.js module aliases
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

// create a Matter.js engine
var engine = Engine.create(document.body);

// create two boxes and a ground
var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80);
var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

// add all of the bodies to the world
World.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);

// run the engine
Engine.run(engine);
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The console shows the following error:

```
" [Matter] warn: No "render.element" passed, "render.canvas" was not inserted into document."
```

I tried to create the render.element and render.canvas, but I'm acting blindly. A "minimal example to get you started" should be already working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure the script is at the bottom of the page (or called on the window load event, or after DOM is ready).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking off part by part of the demo, I found out that most of the code should be in a function, called in the page load, like:

```
<body onload='Start()'>
```

and

```
function Start() {
    // create a Matter.js engine
    var engine = Engine.create(document.getElementById('canvas-container'));

    // create two boxes and a ground
    var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
    var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80);
    var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

    // add all of the bodies to the world
    World.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);

    // run the engine
    Engine.run(engine);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well `document.body` exists in the browser console, but not in JavaScript.

You can use `document.querySelector("body")` instead.

The error probably comes because you passed `undefined` to `Engine.create()`, as `document.body` returns `undefined`.

Also, make sure you execute your code after the `window.onload` event, so that all the *HTMLElements* have been loaded. Like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load",init);
function init(){
    var body = document.querySelector("body");
    // Matter.js module aliases
    var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

    // create a Matter.js engine
    var engine = Engine.create(body);

    // create two boxes and a ground
    var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
    var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80);
    var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

    // add all of the bodies to the world
    World.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);

    // run the engine
    Engine.run(engine);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I have tried with document.getElementById before, and it didn't work either. The onload did the trick.

Comment: Be careful! `document.getElementById(id)` requires an id, and `<body>` doesn't normally have an id, use `document.querySelector(selector)` (more on [**selectors**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)) instead, and also, `window.onload` will replace all previous load event's in `window`, I've updated my answer to use `window.addEventListener()` instead, which does not cause this behaviour. Lastly, if you feel your question has been answered, click the green tick next to the answer! Bye :)

Comment: In my solution I used a <div id='canvas-container'></div>, like they do in the demo. But using Engine.create(document.body) also work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: "Well `document.body` exists in the browser console, but not in JavaScript." Not true. The "browser console" and "JavaScript" are one and the same.

Answer (score 3):

It has been a long time for this question but I see that the library might be improved with new Render object so the new basic sample code is as follows

Include following in `<head>` tags

```
<script src="matter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The JS code can be placed at the bottom of the `<body>` tag

```
<script>

    // module aliases
    var Engine = Matter.Engine,
        Render = Matter.Render,
        World = Matter.World,
        Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

    // create an engine
    var engine = Engine.create();

    // create a renderer
    var render = Render.create({
        element: document.body,
        engine: engine
    });

    // create two boxes and a ground
    var ball = Bodies.circle(420, 15, 20);

    var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
    var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80);
    var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

    // add all of the bodies to the world
    World.add(engine.world, [ball, boxA, boxB, ground]);

    // run the engine
    Engine.run(engine);

    // run the renderer
    Render.run(render);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Minimal single HTML file runnable example (0.19.0)**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39493132/895245 mentioned the key step which is to put the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the `<body>` element.

But for the sake of directness, here it is fully working on a single complete HTML file with the code from https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/wiki/Getting-started/1d138998f05766dc4de0e44ae2e35d03121bb7f2 and using the library hosted from CDNJS https://cdnjs.com/libraries/matter-js for the sake of the demo:

hello.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>hello</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js" integrity="sha512-0z8URjGET6GWnS1xcgiLBZBzoaS8BNlKayfZyQNKz4IRp+s7CKXx0yz7Eco2+TcwoeMBa5KMwmTX7Kus7Fa5Uw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
// module aliases
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    Runner = Matter.Runner,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Composite = Matter.Composite;

// create an engine
var engine = Engine.create();

// create a renderer
var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine
});

// create two boxes and a ground
var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80);
var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

// add all of the bodies to the world
Composite.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);

// create runner
var runner = Runner.create();

// run the engine
Runner.run(runner, engine);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, for local development, you would likely instead want to install locally with:

```
npm install matter-js@0.19.0
```

and instead load the library with:

```
<script src="node_modules/matter-js/build/matter.min.js"></script>
```

as that will free you the need from being online to develop.

And real deployment will then likely want to use NPM and then webpack to bundle all Js into a single file instead as usual.

The example contains two squares falling, and no interactivity enabled:

[image]

[image]