# Disabling gravity in Matter.js

Tags: javascript, matter.js

Is there any way to disable gravity in Matter.js? I want my objects (bodies) to keep their physical abilities (like reaction to collision, restitution, friction etc), but I'd like to prevent the reaction to device's gyro and orientation change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set it on the `Engine` constructor as:

```
const engine = Engine.create({ gravity: { y: 0 } })
```

like any other property. Tested on Matter.js 0.19.0 by modifying this hello world: [How to make minimal example of matter.js work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079138/how-to-make-minimal-example-of-matter-js-work/76203103#76203103)

Answer (score 72):

Try

```
engine.world.gravity.y = 0;
```

where `engine` is your engine instance.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and should be marked as such.

Comment: As a reference, here are the official docs for the gravity properties: https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/World.html#property_gravity

Comment: This is now deprecated and has been replaced with `engine.gravity.y = 0` [as of v0.17.0](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0170-2021-04-11). New docs location: https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Engine.html#property_gravity

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add this to your config:

```
physics: {
    default: "matter",
    matter: {
        gravity: {x: 0, y: 0},
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```