# Disabling gravity for a specific object in Matter.js

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I'm working on a project using Matter.js where I want gravity enabled in general, but I want to be able to disabled and re-enable it for a single object at certain times. I do not want to set that object as static, because I want the physics engine to handle it in other ways, I just don't want gravity to affect it.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466684/disabling-gravity-in-matter-js) that deals with disabling gravity in general, but as I said I want gravity to work for most objects. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: could you load the object into a new world that is contained within the main world?  from browsing the API quickly it looks like this would be the only way http://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/World.html

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple code snippet that you could have toggle on/off to accomplish what you're asking (where `body` is the object that should ignore gravity, and `noGravity` is a boolean that can be toggled to turn it on and off):

```
Events.on(engine, 'beforeUpdate', function() {
    var gravity = engine.world.gravity;

    if (noGravity) {
        Body.applyForce(body, body.position, {
            x: -gravity.x * gravity.scale * body.mass,
            y: -gravity.y * gravity.scale * body.mass
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Extremely helpful answer, thanks. Fixed the problem I was having.

Comment: This just makes my body spin around in one spot. Help?

Comment: @SamSverko same here. Replace `{ x: 0, y: 0 }` with `body.position` to fix. (@Derek can you update the answer?)

Answer (score 6):

Disable the built in gravity and then apply your own selectively, something like this but filter only the bodies you want:

```
engine.world.gravity.scale = 0;

Events.on(engine, 'beforeUpdate', function() {
    var bodies = Composite.allBodies(engine.world);

    for (var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) {
        var body = bodies[i];

        if (body.isStatic || body.isSleeping)
            continue;

        body.force.y += body.mass * 0.001;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but nowadays you can use this:

```js
body.ignoreGravity = true;
```

Comment: As of which version?

Comment: Turns out I was wrong, this is a Phaser specific feature and not supported directly by Matter.js. https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/523

Answer (score 1):

I found that was very easy to implement that. Just look for the                 Engine._bodiesApplyGravity function on the Matter source code and just put whatever condition you need for a body to be excluded.

```
        Engine._bodiesApplyGravity = function (bodies, gravity) {
            var gravityScale = typeof gravity.scale !== 'undefined' ? gravity.scale : 0.001;

            if ((gravity.x === 0 && gravity.y === 0) || gravityScale === 0) {
                return;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) {
                var body = bodies[i];

                // I just added body.ignoreGravity
                if (body.isStatic || body.isSleeping || body.ignoreGravity)  
                    continue;

                // apply gravity
                body.force.y += body.mass * gravity.y * gravityScale;
                body.force.x += body.mass * gravity.x * gravityScale;
            }
        };
```

Comment: What's the best practice to apply this override, without actually touching the original module?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to provide a counter force.  I'm not sure where the 200 is coming from it just worked.  Maybe the engine calculates force twice a cycle.

```
playerBody.force.y = -engine.world.gravity.y / 200;
```

You will have to run it every cycle to keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted an object to follow the mouse. Setting `isStatic: true` made gravity not apply to give me full control over the object's position.

Answer (score -1):

there is an official working example

```
this.matter.add.image(100, 100, 'block').setIgnoreGravity(true);
```

[ignoring gravity phaser3 matter physic](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/physics%5Cmatterjs%5Cignore%20gravity.js)

Comment: Phaser != Matter